# Use aggregated data with elastic search to create a graph on grafana

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate, grafana

I just started using ElasticSearch and Grafana this week (so it might be easy question J) 
I have an ES base which looks like :

```
{
  "title": "Adventure Book",
  "month" : 01-2019,
  "price" : 50
}
```

So for each book, I have the price each month
What I want to do is create a dashboard on Grafana with :

- compute the maximum price of each book
- create an histogram on the number of book per maximum price

I managed to do the first part an create a table with book_id / maximum price.

But then i don't know how i can use my first table "as a source" for my histogram

If you have ideas or workaround to do so it would really help J